# Render in cycle The object disappears and only a shadow remains

Tags: rendering

When I want to render an image so that the floor is transparent and the object with the shadow is visible, only the shadow remains. I used to do that and it worked, but now it doesn't. I had to kick something, I just can't find the reason. Can anyone help? L[image]ink [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KAt7kp4YY-LYHSBLgi1GEBDAU9rxzPfw/view?usp=sharing[2]][2]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KAt7kp4YY-LYHSBLgi1GEBDAU9rxzPfw/view?usp=sharing%5B2%5D%5D%5B2%5D)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file you provided:

- The Render Engine was set to EEVEE.  I changed that to Cycles and enabled GPU compute.
- Render Properties → Film → Transparent was not enabled.  I enabled that.
- The plane did not have Object Properties → Visibility → Shadow Catcher enabled.  I enabled that.

and the biggest problem was:

- The Cube did not have Object Properties → Visibility → Ray Visibility → Camera set.  I enabled that.

The last was the reason why the object wasn't showing up in the Cycles Render

with those changes, I get this render:

[image: rendered image]

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works. I did not think too well and hence the error.

Comment: @Janusz you are very welcome.  Blender's render engines have a lot of settings and sometimes it just takes a bit of work to make sure you have them all set properly.